# Increasing velocity of falling objects

Tags: python

I am trying to increment the speed of a falling object, each time it reaches the top of the screen again.

I already have my objects falling down the way I want them to and reappearing at the top of the screen at random using this code:

```
def Handle_Objeect_Movement(Object_Movement_1, fallingvelocity_1):
    

    if Object_Movement_1.y - fallingvelocity_1 > height:
        Object_Movement_1.y -= fallingvelocity_1 


    Object_Movement_1.y = Object_Movement_1.y + fallingvelocity_1
    if Object_Movement_1.y > height:
                Object_Movement_1.x = random.randrange(0,width)
                Object_Movement_1.y = -200
```

However, now I need the `fallingvelocity_1` to be increased by e.g. 10 each time that the `Object_Movement_1.y` is at -200 or more

I have gotten this kind of right when using this code in my main loop:

```
def main():
    
    Topofscreen = Object_Movement_1.y
    
   
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    open = True
    while open:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        fallingvelocity_1 = 10
        if Topofscreen >= -200:
            fallingvelocity_1 = fallingvelocity_1 + 10
        print(fallingvelocity_1)
```

As I said this kind of works, however the `fallingvelocity_1` is only incremented by 10 once and not every time the object gets back to the top of the screen.

Comment: You should think closely about the concepts of velocity and acceleration. When the object's velocity downwards increases by a given acceleration value (your world's gravity) on each timestep, hey presto, you have realistic-looking gravity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It only gets changed once because you are resetting `fallingvelocity_1` within the while loop so it reset its value to 10 after each iteration of while loop.

Take `fallingvelocity_1 = 10` out of the while loop and then test your code again.

```
fallingvelocity_1 = 10
while open:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    if Topofscreen >= -200:
        fallingvelocity_1 = fallingvelocity_1 + 10
    print(fallingvelocity_1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works perfectly. It was that simple....